# face book integration in android application

Tags: android, facebook, twitter

I developing an android application in which i want to integrate faceebook
and twitter.

I want to post pre-written message on wall of logged in person just on click on "wall post"
button.

Can anyone help me.
Thanks in advance.
sunit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the [Facebook Android SDK](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk). Also take a look at some of its forks. They might have bugfixes and/or extra features.

Comment: Thanks for response, can we post all ready written text on facebook by using this SDK? if yes please explain where i write the text that will display on the wall of user.I want to post all ready written message on wall of logged in person just on click on "wall post" button. please reply

Comment: The Facebook class of the API has a request method that you can use as follows: `facebook.request("me/feed", params, "POST")`, where params is a Bundle with a value "message" in it. You'll have to authorize before you can use this, of course. I suggest checking out the readme or the sample application. Both can be found on the page I linked to in my answer.

Comment: Thank very valuable response but i am not able to implement it till now. after login by using facebook sdk i call facebook.request("me/feed", params, "POST") on wall post button where params is a bundle object like this "params.putString("message", "Tesing done by android application!!!");" but i did not got any response. please help me.how can i implement it. please reply.